# Get the correct hourly block

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, date, momentjs

I need a specific logic for the following use case:

The day is divided in 6 parts => 24h / 6h = 4h

So I have 6 blocks, each one with 4 hours => 00:00, 04:00, 08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00

I need a function that takes a day variable (a Momentjs Object).

If the function gets 11:30 the following block should be returned or visible => 12:00, 16:00, 20:00, 00:00

If the function gets 23:00 the following block should be returned or visible => 00:00, 04:00, 08:00, 12:00

If the function gets 06:00 the following block should be returned or visible => 08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00

Always the next 4 hour blocks.

Comment: `[12:00, 16:00, 20:00, 00:00]` is not valid JS, so what are those elements? Strings? Objects?

Comment: @trincot It doesn't matter. I'm searching for a logic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`isSameOrAfter()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/)

```js
const blocks = ['00:00', '04:00', '08:00', '12:00', '16:00', '20:00']

const hourlyBlock = (time) => {
  let mtime = moment(time, 'hh:mm')
  let index = blocks.findIndex(i => moment(i, 'hh:mm').isSameOrAfter(mtime))
  if (index == -1) index = blocks.length

  return blocks.slice(index, blocks.length).concat(blocks.slice(0, index)).slice(0, 4);
}

console.log(hourlyBlock('11:30').join())
console.log(hourlyBlock('23:00').join())
console.log(hourlyBlock('06:00').join())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZsWP0vT+akWmvEMkNYgZrPHKU9Ke8nYBPC3dqONp1mY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You are just missing `Array.slice()` since OP wanted only 4 blocks returned. The clearest solution to me, though!

Answer (score 2):

You could take the hour part of the date object, and see how many times it divides by 4. Use this to calculate the next 4 blocks. Finally format as you wish to a string:

```js
let dt = moment(); // current date/time
let block = dt.hour() >> 2; // integer division by 4
// Add 1, 2, 3 and 4 to it, and map that to the starting hours of 
//   the next blocks (wrap around midnight using remainder operator)
let blocks = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(i => ((block + i) * 4) % 24);
// format the hours (numbers) as time strings in 00:00 format
console.log( blocks.map(hour => (hour+":00").padStart(5, "0")) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
function getNextBlocks(time){
    // gets hour from time
    var numTime = parseInt(time, 10);

    // rounds up to nearest 6
    var blocks = [Math.ceil(time / 6) * 6];

    // gets the next 3 blocks
    for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        // gets value of previous block and adds 6
        var nextBlock = blocks[i-1] + 6;
    
        // if block is more than 23 it subtracts 24
        if(nextBlock >= 24){
            nextBlock -=24;
        }
    
        blocks.push(nextBlock);
    }

    // adds ":00" to the end of each block
    for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
        blocks[i]+= ":00";
    }

    return blocks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expect?

you can use add hours in moment and convert the result to your needs

```
moment().add(4,'hours').format("HH")
```

after this you can get the time from this result and convert it to your needs
given is an example from what i understood from your question

```
 let now = moment()
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  console.log(now.format("HH") )
  now = now.add(4,'hours') // push this to array or any other datastructure as per your convenience
}
```